# What is the way of sync offline data in android (similar as iClound sync in Apple)?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, synchronization, icloud, offlineapps

I have one application in iPhone that uses iCloud sync to automatic sync local data to the Apple cloud.

Is there any same way to achieve this to the android application?

Comment: Do you want sync your local data to server?

Comment: yes, but not in custom server. something like google drive. Because apple has iclound.

Comment: Have you tried visiting [this StackExchange post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219357/design-for-syncing-data-in-android)?